# Counting the occurrences of a word from a text file in C

Tags: c

The following code is intended to find the occurrences of the word 'if' from a text file chosen by the user, however the result after exiting the loop is always 0. Question is how it could be possibly fixed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    FILE * f;
    int count = 0, i;
    char buf[50], read[100];
    printf("Which file to open\n");
    fgets(buf, 50, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    if (!(f = fopen(buf, "rt"))) {
        printf("Wrong file name");
    } else printf("File opened successfully\n");
    for (i = 0; fgets(read, 100, f) != NULL; i++) {
        if (read[i] == 'if') count++;
    }
    printf("Result is %d", count);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if a sentence contains the word 'cliff'? Does this count as a hit because 'cliff' contains 'if'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if test is wrong.

```
if (read[i]=='if') /* no */
```

Use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcmp.html)

```
if (strcmp(read[i], "if") == 0) /* check if the strings are equal */
```

Comment: Fine, that worked. Thanks for answer! In fact that was what I changed **while(fscanf(f, "%s", &next)!=EOF){
                if (strcmp(read, "if")==0)
                    count++;** Perhaps I didn't use the for loop properly way as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. `'if'` isn't what you think it is; it's a multicharacter literal, not a string.
2. You can't compare strings with `==` in C.  Use `strcmp(3)`.
3. Your loop doesn't look like it does what you want either; time to break out a debugger (and probably `strtok(3)`).

Comment: Also no need to write `buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';`.

Comment: Why? I don't think so.

Comment: It simply doesn't open the file successfully. Returns the if statement - "Wrong file name".

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `read[i]` only contains a single character and will never be equal to any multi-character word.

For another, single apostrophe's are used to define single characters. `'if'` is not a string of characters.

You will need to parse each line to find each individual word, and then compare each word to the target word using something like `stricmp()`.